# java.sql.SQLException: Field 'passwordConfirmation' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I've been scratching my head over this error for sometime now but can't work it out. I've been using Hibernate 3 to persist **User** entity. But I am getting **java.sql.SQLException: Field 'passwordConfirmation' doesn't have a default value** error when I try to do that.

Following is my **User** entity:
**User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirmation;    
    private String captcha; 

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @NotEmpty   
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirmation() {
        return passwordConfirmation;
    }
    public void setPasswordConfirmation(String passwordConfirmation) {
        this.passwordConfirmation = passwordConfirmation;
    }

}
```

Could someone help me understand that why am I getting this error?

Comment: Oracle is telling _you are not supplying a value for the `passwordConfirmation` field_. How/where are you populating the `User` object?

Comment: @Nivas: I am representing the form using spring mvc 3 and then I fill the form but when I submit the form, I get this error.

Comment: I am not aware of Spring MVC. But the problem is the passwordConfirmation field is not populated when the data is persisted to the database. Can you try looking around the place where this should be updated but is not...

Comment: @Nivas: I don't have any column for `passwordConfirmation` in my database and when I submit the form I see the value of `passwordConfirmation` being populated in the model being used for validating the equality of `password` and `passwordConfirmation` field. Did you mean update `passwordConfirmation` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`passwordConfirmation` property in your class is marked as `@Transient`, although error indicates that column for that field exists in the database schema.

If your database schema was generated automatically by Hibenrate, perhaps it had been done before you added a `@Transient` annotation. If so, you need to regenerate your schema.

Comment: Yes, I used hibernate to create the schema but even after dropping and recreating the schema its giving me the same result.

Comment: @skip: Are you sure `@Transient` is a `javax.persistence.Transient`?

Comment: Even I doubted it for a moment but yes its `javax.persistence.Transient` only.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistakenly using a different schema than the one I was generating using Hibernate. Both the schema had `passwordConfirmation` field in the User entity so got confused.

I've got it working now. Thanks :)

Comment: Then please mark axtavt's answer as correct so others who read his answer know instantly it fixed your problem. thx